# NodeMCU ESP32s can't get Vin to work?

Tags: power, battery, esp32

Trying to power the board with a 9V battery through VIN. As the documentation says, it can take input voltage of 6-12 Volts, but when I connect the 9V battery, all it does is power the board on and nothing else happens.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am stupid had the ground connected to the wrong pin thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: What kind of 9V battery?

Comment: Just a regular 9V E-Block Battery.

Comment: Yes, but what chemistry?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a 9V block battery: They don't deliver the current you need for the esp32 to run/create an access point/act as a client. What you can do is connect 6 AA batteries in a row (6*1.5V = 9V) and they will deliver a higher current than the 9V block.